# How do I make spaces between labels?

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

I am working with **MPAndroidChart** library in Android.

I want to make spaces between labels in XAxis in my `BarChart` without hiding the labels.

I use this code but this hide labels and does not make space between points in xAxis:

```
mChart.setPinchZoom(false);

mChart.setDrawBarShadow(false);
mChart.setDrawGridBackground(false);

XAxis xAxis = mChart.getXAxis();
xAxis.setPosition(XAxisPosition.BOTTOM);
xAxis.setSpaceBetweenLabels(6);
xAxis.setXOffset(12);
xAxis.setTextSize(10);
xAxis.setDrawGridLines(false);
```

This is how it looks like currently:

[image: lables in xAxis look so close to each other]

in the image lables in xAxis is so close to each other how can i make space between them

Comment: The question is missing information. Which library is being used? `BarChart` is a part of Android SDK!

Comment: You should add this to your question body/description as well.

Comment: ok edited, do you have solution?

Answer (score 3):

Try `barDataSet.setBarSpacePercent(20f);`  and
`20f` is the example value you can set as per your requirement.

Comment: ok this method is available for the BarDataSet object, so i make `BarDataSet set1 = new BarDataSet(yVals1, "duration min");
         set1.setColor(Color.GREEN);
       
         set1.setDrawValues(false);
         set1.setLabel("duration min");
         set1.setBarSpacePercent(60f);` and also i need to add setSpaceBetweenLabels for xAxis

Comment: The problem of lables still the same, labels still so close to each other, but the dataset(in green) are not close anymore, the width of each data set is now smaller

Comment: Okay i think it is not available currently in the MPChart, the only way is to increase the Bar size and it automatically make space for lables

Comment: @Philipp Thanks for editing and making it correct And `MPAndroidChart` is the best library you did a great job